# Is it possible to retrieve the data If I give cat >filename.txt in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

Instead of giving **cat filename.txt**,I gave as **cat >filename.txt**.My whole content in filename.txt got erased.Can I retrieve the content back?Where it will get stored?
If anyone knows,please help me to get the content back..

Comment: The content is most likely still stored on the disk, but you'll need recovery tools to read the physical disk to try to find the original contents.

Comment: check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files

Comment: Depending on your file system type, a combination of `grep` and `dd` might do the trick but it's no sure-fire method. `dd` can mess up your entire system if you make a similar typo again so be careful. Check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files/2680#2680

Comment: You could also see if your text editor backed up the file. If you ever noticed filenames ending with a tilde `~`, you've seen them. Maybe try `find -type f -iname '*~' | grep name_or_partial_name_of_your_file`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply.I used recovery tool photorec,and when I give find -type f -iname '*~' | grep filename.txt ,it's showing ./filename.txt~.But I don't know how to see the content inside it.

Comment: I used cat command to see the content of filename.txt~,but the content is not there.My doubt is,If I give cat >filename.txt,the file is not actually deleted,only the content is removed.I tried all the above options but I couldn't get it. Is cat >filename.txt is same as deleting the file?Can I use the same option to recover it?                                                      Note:My filename.txt is still present,only the content is not available and I need only the content back.

Comment: Consider the file as lost. Can you scroll back in your screen and see part of the content? Download it again? Rewrite it with new energy?

Answer (score 1):

My sympathies for your (data) loss.

One way to prevent this in the future is to use the "noclobber" shell setting:

```
$ touch veryImportantFile
$ cat >veryImportantFile 
uh oh
$ cat veryImportantFile 
uh oh
$ set -o noclobber
$ cat >veryImportantFile 
bash: veryImportantFile: cannot overwrite existing file
$ echo "I really want to overwrite" >| veryImportantFile 
$ cat veryImportantFile 
I really want to overwrite
```

Note the use of the `>|` redirector to force overwriting.